# Camera app to save and modify exif data

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I am working on an ios app to use the camera to click a picture and save it. I want to differentiate these images so that a desktop application can later access them without accessing any other pictures in the roll. I thought about modifying the EXIF data but am not sure how the copy and paste works when the device is connected to a windows machine and if it strips out the EXIF data or not. Does anyone have any solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The EXIF data is not removed if you copy the images from an iOS device to an OS X or Windows computer. You could either modify the EXIF data or even name the files with a pattern that your desktop application recognizes.